# MYSQL Query - grabbing all the records that meet the criteria 3 or more times

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, count, group-by

Not sure how to do this but I am trying to grab all the parcels from a MYSQL DB that have had multiple years of delinquencies. Right now I can count how many delinquencies I have for the years given using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    parcel, COUNT(*), due
FROM 
    `deliquent_property`
WHERE year IN ('2013', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009') AND
      CAST(replace(replace(ifnull(due,0),',',''),'$','') AS decimal(10,2)) > 0
GROUP BY parcel
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

So I get something like this

```
'XXX-XXX-XXX1'    '3'  '167.00'
'XXX-XXX-XXX2'    '4'  '190'
```

Where the amount is the last record for that parcel in the DB. The problem is what I really want is a list of parcels with each years overdue amount shown, something like this (skipping those that do not have a least 3 delinquencies):

```
'XXX-XXX-XXX1'    '2013'  '1267.78'
'XXX-XXX-XXX1'    '2012'  '1000.38'
'XXX-XXX-XXX1'    '2011'  '167.00'
'XXX-XXX-XXX2'    '2013'  '1000.00'
'XXX-XXX-XXX2'    '2012'  '500.00'
'XXX-XXX-XXX2'    '2011'  '100.00'
'XXX-XXX-XXX2'    '2010'  '190.00'
```

I am half way there but I am lost on getting this last part.

Comment: Thank you Vahid Hallaji for reformatting my question, how did you get the code to show up right, I tried the code markers but that did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table back to your list.  Here is one way:

```
select dp.*
from delinquent_property dp join
     (SELECT parcel, COUNT(*)
      FROM delinquent_property
      WHERE year IN ('2013', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009') AND
           CAST(replace(replace(ifnull(due,0),',',''),'$','') AS decimal(10,2)) > 0
     GROUP BY parcel
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
    ) p3
    on dp.parcel = p3.parcel
where CAST(replace(replace(ifnull(due,0),',',''),'$','') AS decimal(10,2)) > 0
order by parcel;
```

Comment: I think your join should be `ON dp.parcel = p3.parcel`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, for some reason the join is including records with a zero due, and there does not seem to be ordering by parcel. Oh I did have to add an '*' on the COUNT(*) > 2 otherwise I get a syntax error. The number of records returned went from several hundred to several thousand (even if all five years were non zero I would not get that many records). I am not sure I understand why the join is doing this, as what you suggest makes sense?

Comment: @CharlesBunn . . . The right syntax should be `having count(*) > 2`.  Does that fix the problem?

Comment: No the syntax fix does not fix the problem, I did the fix just to get it to run...

Comment: @CharlesBunn . . . I think the problem is that it returns all the records for a given parcel that meets the condition -- but some of the years might be ok.  I added the `where` condition to the outer query as well.

Comment: That partly worked it got rid of the records with a zero due, but the parcels are not sorted together, they are scattered throughout the query results. I would think the GROUP BY parcel would sort these together but apparently that only is in the aggregate HAVING COUNT(*) > 2. I tried a second GROUP BY parcel at the end but that did not work and it cut the results by a third for some reason. I guess the question would be how do you make a GROUP BY work across a JOIN.

Comment: @CharlesBunn . . . If you want the results in a particular order, then always include an `order by` clause.  MySQL happens to guarantee the ordering after a `group by`, but this is not standard SQL.